# Component renderer for vaadin grid

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin

I would like to switch from vaadin table to the everywhere praised grid but i don't know how to overcome limitation that grid cannot render components. In the table I have column that displays HorizontalLayout with dynamic number of buttons. Grid allows to use Button renderer but it means only one button will be rendered in each column and I need it more flexible. Perhaps I could write my own Rendere to support what I need but it requires some lower level/gwt/javascript programming and I am not sure if the desired result is even achievable. Dear vaadin guys, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 5):

I just finished a component renderer for the grid. It is fully functional, but not tested in production scenarios. It is a start and I hope people are joining the development.

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer

https://github.com/datenhahn/componentrenderer

Answer (score 3):

The component support is a feature that I'd love to see in Grid as well. Getting to low level GWT stuff really breaks the abstraction and it will cause head aches especially for maintenance. If there is nothing special in Grid that you need, I'd just use Table. It's still supported for a long time and probably more stable than Grid which is still quite new beast.

Alternatively you could try using this experiment, which actually brings a component support to Grid. I haven't yet tried it, but it looks promising:

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/beangrid-add-on

Answer (score 2):

## `ComponentRenderer` now available in Vaadin 8.1

Update: Vaadin 8.1 now supports having a component as the content of your Grid cell.

This feature is currently listed as # 1 on the list of the [*What’s New*](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew) page.

> Starting with 8.1, you can render any Vaadin UI component, such as Buttons, CheckBoxes, TextFields, or custom components, inside Grid's cells. In previous versions, you needed to write these using client side code or pre-defined Renderer classes.

See [video](https://vaadin.com/framework/whatsnew#video-components-in-grid).

See [*Sampler* demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/component-renderer).

See [the guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html), scrolling half-way down for `ComponentRenderer`.

In related news, Grid now has new HTML5-based Drag-and-Drop support, and there is a new [TreeGrid](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/tree-grid/tree-sample) widget.